# Keep option value selected after button click

Tags: php

On new search, I don't want it to reset to Monday. I want it to go after what's in my

```
$dag = $_GET["vdag"];
```

I think I'm close, but I can't find out what I'm missing. Any suggestions?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="get">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls form-inline"
 <label for="inputValue">Choose day</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="vdag">
        <option value="1" <?= ($dag === 1 ? 'selected="selected"' : '')?>>Monday</option>
        <option value="2" <?= ($dag === 2 ? 'selected="selected"' : '')?>>Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3" <?= ($dag === 3 ? 'selected="selected"' : '')?>>Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4" <?= ($dag === 4 ? 'selected="selected"' : '')?>>Thursday</option>
        <option value="5" <?= ($dag === 5 ? 'selected="selected"' : '')?>>Friday</option>
      </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search
    </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

<?php
    $dag = $_GET["vdag"];        <------ Here I get my number , 1 to 5
<!-- And more php code!-->
```

Sorry if I'm not clear.

Comment: So you define `$dag` __after__ using it and ask us what to do?

Comment: Check `isset($_GET['vdag'])` and define your $dag variable at top of the page.

Comment: First i chose an option, And after i press buttonklick, I get the option value in $dag, but my roll-down list goes back to default = Monday...
If i chose thursday, i want thurday to be first after buttonclick

Comment: 1). Close div element properly <div class="controls form-inline" , you missing a ">" here. 2). $dag = $_GET["vdag"];   should be placed before your dropdown starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this working code

```html
<?php
        if (isset($_GET["vdag"])) {
            $dag = $_GET["vdag"];
        } else {
            $dag = 1;
        }
        ?>
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="get">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls form-inline"
                     <label for="inputValue">Choose day</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="vdag">
                        <option value="1" <?= ($dag == 1 ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>>Monday</option>
                        <option value="2" <?= ($dag == 2 ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>>Tuesday</option>
                        <option value="3" <?= ($dag == 3 ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>>Wednesday</option>
                        <option value="4" <?= ($dag == 4 ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>>Thursday</option>
                        <option value="5" <?= ($dag == 5 ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>>Friday</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, just gonna try it and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you man its working, Do you know why its so sensitive with three === ? i found it on other peoples post and copied it.